# Does Safari supports Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?

Tags: safari, cors, apple-expose

I need to read the `Location` header using XHR. I have added an `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header to the OPTIONS response and to the response where I need to read the header:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location
```

This works in Chrome, Firefox and IE10, but not in Safari 5.1.7.

Does Safari support the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

After glancing at versions of the `CORS` spec, my guess is that `Safari 5.1` (and similar versions) were using a build of webkit that did not include support for the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header. This wasn't added to the `CORS` spec draft until July of 2010. `Safari 5.1` was released in July of 2011. According to this message thread, `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` support wasn't added to webkit until sometime after November 2011, which means `Safari 5.1` definitely did not support this. According to this webkit/safari bug support wasn't added until mid-January 2012, meaning that the earliest version to contain this support would be 5.1.7 (but possibly even later).